# Running in Karaf (OSGi) with JJWT version 0.11.1 getting Unable to load class io.jasonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider

Tags: osgi, classloader, jjwt

Running in Karaf (OSGi) getting Unable to load class io.jasonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider

The version of jjwt is 0.11.1

my bundles include jjwt-api (provided) and jjwt-jackson (compile) and I have jjwt-impl running as a bundle.

do I need to create a "mega-bundle" to have this work?

Comment: sorry, the version 0.11.1 is related to JJWT and NOT Karaf :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in JJWT 0.11.2.  Please upgrade. :)

Comment: Thank you Les.  I'll see if I can get it into this cycle!

Answer (score 0):

so, I got this working, but not ideal.

first, jjwt-impl, though having all the normal OSGi tags, does NOT export anything.

so, I had to do two things - VERY BAD, but I couldn't figure out how else:

1) replace the thread-class-loader surrounding the calls to signature methods to the current bundle class-loader.

2) embed jjwt-impl in the calling osgi bundle and export:

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>false</Embed-Transitive>

 <Export-Package>
     {local-packages},
     io.jsonwebtoken,
     io.jsonwebtoken.lang,
     io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto
 </Export-Package>
```

Comment: note: you have to do the same thing with the jackson json support bundle and export package: io.jsonwebtoken.jackson.io

Comment: I *just* released JJWT 0.11.2, which has a fix for this.  Please allow 30 minutes for the version to show in Maven Central and then upgrade and try again.  Background: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/pull/580

Comment: Les, just checked https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl ....  no 0.11.2 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Peter Berkman method with some modifications.

in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                <Karaf-Commands>org.foo.app</Karaf-Commands>
                            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                <Karaf-Commands>org.foo.app</Karaf-Commands>
                <!-- dependencies inside the bundle -->
                <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                <Export-Package>
                    {local-packages},
                    io.jsonwebtoken,
                    io.jsonwebtoken.lang,
                    io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto
                </Export-Package> -->
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
                <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

in features.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0"name="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}">
    <feature name="${project.artifactId}" version="${project.version}"
             description="${project.description}">
    <feature>onos-api</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.11.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl/0.11.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson/0.11.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</bundle>

</feature>
```